# PHP Data Object insert not executing

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My PHP form I just changed to use PDO. The only thing I can tell is the execute is not working. Am I supposed to pass something with it?

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=x;charset=utf8', 'x', 'x');
if ( !$db )
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM ucm_signup WHERE email =? ");
$stmt->bindValue(1, $mail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->rowCount()== 0) { 
//if there are no duplicates...insert
$sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO ucm_signup (company, address1, address2, city, province, zip, fname, lname, email, phone, session, iama, buyfrom, group1, ipaddress)
VALUES (:company, :address1, :address2, :city, :province, :zip, :fname, :lname, :mail, :phone, :session, :iama, :buyfrom, :group1, :ipaddress)");
    $sql->bindParam(":company", $_POST['company'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":address1", $_POST['address1'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":city", $_POST['city'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":province", $_POST['province'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":zip", $_POST['zip'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":fname", $_POST['fname'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":lname", $_POST['lname'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":email", $_POST['email'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":phone", $_POST['phone'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":session", $_POST['session'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":imea", $_POST['imea'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":buyfrom", $_POST['buyfrom'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":imea", $_POST['imea'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":group1", $_POST['group1'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":ipaddress", $_POST['ipaddress'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->execute();
}
```

My database table has no records. Thank you

Comment: You don't seem to be setting a value for the parameter `:address2`

Comment: No value binded for `:iama` instead you have bind the value to `:imea` which doesnot exist in your query same for `:mail` case also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing some placeholder in your bind parameters, check them carefully

```
$sql->bindParam(":address1", $_POST['address1'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":address2", $_POST['city'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
//address2 was missed, probably error is column doesn't match values
$sql->bindParam(":email", $_POST['email'],PDO::PARAM_STR); //supposed to be mail
$sql->bindParam(":imea", $_POST['imea'],PDO::PARAM_STR); //supposed to be iama
```

You might want to check for [**`pdo errors`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php), here an example taken from manual

```
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

With this attribute correctly added pdo will notify you if any error occur

Comment: [`You missed one / or two`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22543667/php-data-object-insert-not-executing#comment34309231_22543667) ;-)

Comment: Because in case you make errors, like now, pdo will tell you what's the problem with your query

Comment: Actually, it would be easier to just change `:iama` to `:imea` since all other words are `imea`, instead of making 3 changes. ;-)

Comment: Yes probably it would be

Comment: Great help, I like the error check! Thanks for the resource

Comment: You are welcome dude, debugging is the base of programming though

Comment: Agreed, I will go punish myself by taking a couple shots. :D

Answer (score 2):

PHP users are so PHP users.

First they're laboring on a WALL of code, consists of constantly repeating nearly hundred variables.
Then they get totally lost.

While everything can be done with short and concise code, writing each field name only **ONCE**

```
$allowed = array('company', 'address1', 'address2', 'city', 'province', 
                 'zip', 'fname', 'lname', 'email', 'phone', 'session', 
                 'iama', 'buyfrom', 'group1', 'ipaddress');
$_POST['ipaddress'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO ucm_signup SET ".pdoSet($allowed, $values);
$stm = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute($values);
```

where `pdoSet()` helper function can be stored elsewhere and *reused* for the every insert or update query

```
function pdoSet($fields, &$values, $source = array()) {
  $set = '';
  $values = array();
  if (!$source) $source = &$_POST;
  foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if (isset($source[$field])) {
      $set.="`".str_replace("`","``",$field)."`". "=:$field, ";
      $values[$field] = $source[$field];
    }
  }
  return substr($set, 0, -2); 
}
```