# PDO prepared statements and their execution

Tags: php, pdo

I have recently 'upgraded' from MYSQL* to PDO, and I have a couple of related questions:

1/ I have a form on the webpage which submits alot of data. Rather than have 1 looong prepared statement with maybe 50 items in it, Id like to split it into maybe 5 separate statements:

```
//TODs
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE first_page_data(tod_house, tod_bung, tod_flat, tod_barnc, tod_farm, tod_small, tod_build, tod_devland, tod_farmland) SET(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) WHERE email_address=?");

$stmt->bindValue(1, $_POST['tod_house'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(2, $_POST['tod_bung'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(3, $_POST['tod_flat'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(4, $_POST['tod_barnc'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(5, $_POST['tod_farm'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(6, $_POST['tod_small'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(7, $_POST['tod_build'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(8, $_POST['tod_devland'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(9, $_POST['tod_farmland'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(10, $_SESSION['buyer_email']);
$stmt->execute();
```

This is the first of 5 blocks. If I didnt split it this statement would be 50 items long. My question is would there be any noticable adverse effects to splitting it up? Speed, pressure on the server, etc... as there would be 5 smaller updates to the database rather than 1 big one.

2/ My second question is quite simple - is the code above considered 'safe'? Ive seen people put the $_POST values into a variable (mostly because of MYSQL) and then into the statements. Ive read that using PDO prevents any injections and so the POST values can be put straight into bindValue but im not entirely sure!

Comment: Better a big one, you will only have one query to execute instead of many and you will reduce memory used. And yes you code is safe

Comment: 1. the only drawback is amount of code you have to write. 2. it is safe. 3. the amount of code can be reduced dramatically, as it can be seen from the [answer to the very recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22543957/285587)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's safe (PDO::prepare takes care of that), and one big statement is more efficient that a series of smaller ones.  But you can script your code to make it less painful to read and edit.  Suggestions:

1. Put the query in a string and make it more vertical, one line per parameter.  Heredoc syntax is great for this and avoids concatenation.
2. Use :whatever in the query instead of the numbered values, just for clarity and portability.
3. Instead of calling bindValue repeatedly, you could build an array and then pass it whole to execute();  Arrays are the simplest thing PHP can do, and should be less overhead than calling bindValue repeatedly, though the real difference is probably negligible.

   `$arrParams[] = array(':tod_house' => $_POST["tod_house"];`

   `$stmt->execute($arrParams);`

Comment: Good advice, but how do I specify between the different datatypes using the array method?

Comment: With arrays, all values are treated as strings, so maybe that doesn't work for you if you're receiving parameter values back?  But for the update itself it doesn't matter, since an SQL statement is a string and it's up to MySQL to cast values according to the column assigned.

Comment: I never knew that! Why is there even an option to specify the parameter datatype when your binding parameters to an insert/update statement if the server interprets it according to the database settings?

Comment: @Giovanni sometimes you need a special type but in general string is enough

Comment: @BarryDevSF you better verify this latter statement of yours.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, I can't verify so I deleted my comment.  I assumed because I can't see much other purpose for the typing, but I can't find any documentation that PDO validates bindValue by data type.

Comment: Honestly, the implementation if this thing with types in PDO is almost insane. Partly because PDO have to support wide range or DBMS, partly of just design failures. In my wrapper I have a fix for a most weird one: when even if you set TYPE_INT explicitly, PDO will bind your value as string anyway.

Comment: That wide range of DBMS supported is probably the cause.  I notice Oracle has a special extension, noted in PDO documentation as "experimental," which makes me wonder what the experiments are.