# PHP Data Object execute issue

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpmyadmin

My PHP form is POSTing to a php file that connects to my database and supposed to INSERT the record.

As of now I have tested the connection and it is working, my SELECT statement is working. But my INSERT is not. I did an `echo $sql->rowCount();` before the execution and it returns "0". Should there be a row per value?

My code:

```
try {
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=x;charset=utf8', 'x', 'x');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=x;charset=utf8', 'x', 'x');
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO ucm_signup (company, address1, address2, city, province, zip, fname, 
        lname, email, phone, session, iama, buyfrom, ipaddress)
VALUES (:company, :address1, :address2, :city, :province, :zip, :fname, :lname, :email, :phone, :session, :iama, :buyfrom, :ipaddress)");

$sql->bindParam(":company", $_POST['company'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":address1", $_POST['address1'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":address2", $_POST['address2'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":city", $_POST['city'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":province", $_POST['province'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":zip", $_POST['zip'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":fname", $_POST['fname'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":lname", $_POST['lname'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":email", $_POST['email'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":phone", $_POST['phone'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":session", $_POST['session'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":iama", $_POST['iama'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":buyfrom", $_POST['buyfrom'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(":ipaddress", $_POST['ipaddress'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->execute();
  //$db = null;
  //header( "Location: http://www.x.com/company/ucm_signup2" );
```

Any ideas on why my execute is not correct? Thank you

Comment: Which execute? What error messages are you getting (displayed or in logs)? Is `$_POST['ipaddress']` actually set, or should you be using `$ipaddress`?

Comment: does `$sql->rowCount();` before an execute even make sense? the query hasn't been sent to the database so there's going to be no results.

Comment: Can you qualify "my SELECT statement is working. But my INSERT is not"?

Comment: Refer to @N.B. answer.

Comment: What is the difference between this question and your [`other question`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22543667/)? If your other question successfully inserts into DB, then what is the issue now? @DDDD Are you trying to check if a value already exists?

Comment: @Fred-ii- My other question was related to not executing at all. Now the execute code is being run. Just not inserting. The other question got me as far as running the execute code. :/

Comment: This question could have been avoided. We like to help people out when there are actual problems with code, but this question is about mixing variables. Voting to close. I don't see how anyone would benefit from this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mixing variables.

Comment: I agree, I tried to delete, but couldn't. :/

Comment: @DDDD Nothing personal ;-)

Comment: it is rather on the premises. IF it does execute, then it inserts too. If there is no insert - then no execute as well. It's all in vain though...

Comment: @YourCommonSense Can you vote to close?

Comment: I never vote. In the answer I gave you other day, this problem was solved. Surely you paid attention to it.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, surely I did. I was all wrapped up in understanding PDO though. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your parameters mixed

```
......
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
......
```

Later

```
$sql->bindParam(":ipaddress", $_POST['ipaddress'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

There is no  `$_POST['ipaddress']`

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several logical errors. First error is relying on PDO to provide you with `rowCount()`.  It is not reliable with SELECT statements.

The second error you have is checking for duplicate records on PHP's side. That's wrong.
Imagine yourself registering with twice with the same email. There's a brief lag between PHP and MySQL and during that time the server can accept two requests, both carrying the same payload (email), and before any insert occurred - you (wrongly) inspected that there indeed isn't such an email in the database.

What you end up are duplicates. Now expand the example to more than 2 requests.

You can't perform **data integrity checks** in PHP.

Third error you did was perform a SELECT and then count rows. Instead, you should have done

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as num_records FROM table WHERE condition = :condition
```

You will always have the result from that query. And there's less data to transfer.

So what should you do? Simply - add the UNIQUE constraint to the email field, *try* to insert the data and catch the Exception. If the exception message says "duplicate key for entry..." then you know the email is taken and you can send the appropriate message to the client.

You don't need to query with SELECT first.
You don't need to check number of rows.
You are 100% sure that data integrity is ok.
You end up with less code.